# How to hook global WM_APPCOMMAND message?

Tags: c#, hook, message, global

I'm writting a simple music player. I want it hook global `WM_APPCOMMAND` message (`APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY`, `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PAUSE`, `APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_NEXTTRACK`,...).
Can you help me how to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)` but it can not hook global message :( I also dont want use keyboard hook because I'm having a gloabal hook app, and use it to send `WM_APPCOMMAND` to Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires a WH_SHELL hook, set by SetWindowsHookEx().  The hook callback will get the [HSHELL_APPCOMMAND notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644991%28VS.85%29.aspx).

This hook requires a DLL that can be injected into all running processes.  You cannot write such a DLL in a managed language like C#, the process you'll try to inject will not have the CLR loaded.  Unmanaged code is required, C is the typical choice.  [This project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H) ought to be helpful to get such a DLL going.  Do beware the considerable complications on a 64-bit operating system, you'll need two helper programs so you can inject both 32-bit and 64-bit processes.